# Como criar um arquivo txt e fazer download?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Uso o código abaixo para gerar um arquivo txt em Windows Forms:

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("D:\teste.txt");
List<Producao> bpa = ProducaoDados.BuscarBPAC(txtCompetencia.Text);
foreach (Producao linha in bpa)
    {
    file.WriteLine(
    "02" +
    linha.Unidade +
    linha.Competencia.Substring(3, 4) + linha.Competencia.Substring(0, 2) + //competencia
    linha.Cbo +
    string.Format("{0:000}", linhaTexto) + string.Format("{0:00}", linhaItem) +
    linha.Procedimento +
    "000" +
    string.Format("{0:000000}", linha.Quant) +
    "EXT"
    );

    linhaItem++;
    if (linhaItem > 20)
    {
        linhaItem = 1;
        linhaTexto++;
    }
}
```

Quero saber como incluir esse código em um projeto `MVC`, o sistema criar esse arquivo e no final, surgir a opção pro usuário baixar o mesmo em sua máquina.

Answer (score 1):

Essa questão já é um pouco antiga e responder parece que estou chegando bem atrasado para a festa. Mas como sei que isso pode ajudar alguém, mesmo assim vou dar minha resposta.
Partindo de um projeto Asp.Net MVC vou mostrar primeiramente como gerar o arquivo .txt.

Primeiramente é necessário inserir um objeto do tipo IWebHostEnvironment na injeção de dependência da controller para que possa conseguir o caminho do servidor para gravar o arquivo.

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _appEnvironment;

public BlogController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  _appEnvironment = env;
}
```

Neste exemplo, estou buscando uma lista de url's de artigos de um site.
A controller busca essa lista de url's e transforma em um arquivo .txt e grava em wwwroot/UrlsArtigos/Urls.txt.
Veja o código abaixo:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ListarUrlPost()
{
  var postBanco = Task.Run(() => _pServicoDeDados.ListUrlArtigos());

  await postBanco;

  for(int i = 0; i < postBanco.Result.ListaUrlPost.Count; i++)
  {
    postBanco.Result.ListaUrlPost[i] = "https://www.meudominio.com" + "/" + postBanco.Result.ListaUrlPost[i];
  }

  string localSave = Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath, "UrlsArtigos/Urls.txt");

  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(localSave))
  {
    postBanco.Result.ListaUrlPost.ForEach(url =>
    {
      sw.WriteLine(url);
    });
  }

  return View(postBanco.Result);
}
```

Depois que o arquivo é gerado, é aberta uma tela com a lista das url's dos artigos, e tem um botão que vai fazer o download do arquivo. Ao clicar no botão a action abaixo será acionada e o arquivo será baixado.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public FileResult DownloadUrlPost()
    {
      string contentType = "application/txt";
      //Os parametros para o arquivo são
      //1. o caminho do aruivo on servidor
      //2. o tipo de conteudo do tipo MIME
      //3. o parametro para o arquivos salvo pelo navegador
      return File("\\UrlsArtigos\\Urls.txt", contentType, "Report.txt");
    }
```